# Value of distances between randomly generated points in a 3D projection

Tags: normal-distribution, random

Suppose you Randomly generate n points using a uniform distribution, (x,y,z) where x,y, and z are between 0 and 1. Calculate the distance between a point and all the other points calculated, then take the average of those distances and assign that value to that point. Repeat the process for all points in the set, then take the average of all generated values and label it k. As n approaches infinity, what does the value of k converge to?

Comment: If you’re looking for a visual representation, I’m calculating probable distances between points in a cube with side length 1(although that may not really matter here). I suspected the value might be (-1+sqrt(2))/2, but I’m unsure of if that’s true, or if it is, how to prove it.

Comment: You're quite right in thinking that this can be rephrased using a continuous approximation. However, if we're considering the average magnitude of the distance, the resulting integral is a bit of a mess. If you instead use the Root Mean Square (rms) distance, everything works out simply to $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$.

Comment: @Kajelad thanks